# $L^p$ norm equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to show $A = ||Du||_{L^p}$ is equivalent to $B = \sum_{|\alpha| = 1} ||D^{\alpha} u ||_{L^p}$ in the sense of norms where $ p \geq 1$ by using Jensen's inequality.

$B^p = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \int_U |u_{x_i}|^p \right)^{1/p} = \left[ \left(\int_U |u_{x_1}|^p\right)^{1/p} + \cdots + \left(\int_U |u_{x_n}|^p\right)^{1/p}\right]= ( a_1 + \cdots + a_n)^p $

and it would be nice if I can somehow show $ A^p = \int_U |Du|^p = \int_U \left(\sqrt{u_{x_1}^2 + \cdots + u_{x_n}^2}\right) ^p$ is greater than $n^{p-1} (a_1^p + \cdots + a_n^p)$ in order to use Jensen's inequality
$$ (a_1^p + \cdots a_n^p) \leq (a_1+\cdots a_n)^p \leq  n^{p-1} (a_1^p + \cdots a_n^p)$$

Any tips please?

Comment: What are $a_j$'s in your context? And do I understand correctly that you already know how to justify one (of two) inequality?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you aim for. Usually you show one inequality and that the space is complete with both norms. The other inequality then comes from the open mapping theorem.

Comment: $a_i = \left( \int_U |u_{x_i}|^p \right)^{1/p} $

Comment: I am trying to show there exist $C_1, C_2$ such that $ C_1 \; B^p \leq A^p \leq C_2 B^p$ which is basically $ C_1 \; B \leq A \leq C_2 \; B$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $2\le p$ (a reverse argument holds for $p\le 2$). By the arithmetic mean inequalities, $$\frac{|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|}{n}\le\sqrt{\frac{|a_1|^2+\cdots+|a_n|^2}{n}}\le\sqrt[p]{\frac{|a_1|^p+\cdots+|a_n|^p}{n}}\le\max_i|a_i|\tag{1}$$ Hence
$$|a_1+\cdots+a_n|\le n^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{|a_1|^2+\cdots+|a_n|^2}\le n^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\sqrt[p]{|a_1|^p+\cdots+|a_n|^p}\tag{2} $$
$$\sqrt[p]{|a_1|^p+\cdots+|a_n|^p}\le (|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|)\le n^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{|a_1|^2+\cdots+|a_n|^2}\tag{3}$$

Therefore
\begin{align}A=\|Du\|_p&=\sqrt[p]{\int(|u_1|^2+\cdots+|u_n|^2)^{p/2}}\\&\le n^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}\sqrt[p]{\int(|u_1|^p+\cdots+|u_n|^p)}\qquad\textrm{by (2)}\\&\le n^{\frac{1}{2}}\max_i\|u_i\|_p\le n^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_i\|u_i\|_p=n^{\frac{1}{2}}B\qquad\textrm{by (1)}\end{align}

Conversely, \begin{align}B=\sum_i\|u_i\|_p&\le n^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\sqrt[p]{\|u_1\|_p^p+\cdots+\|u_n\|_p^p}\qquad\textrm{by (2)}\\
&=n^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\sqrt[p]{\int|u_1|^p+\cdots|u_n|^p}\\
&\le  n^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}\sqrt[p]{\int\left(|u_1|^2+\cdots+|u_n|^2\right)^{p/2}}\qquad \textrm{by (3)}\\
&=n^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}\|Du\|_p=n^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}A\end{align}